# How can I insert line breaks to reworded commit messages during git interactive rebase?

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

I want to insert line breaks in the middle of commit messages while rewording them in interactive rebase. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Notepad++ as the external editor for interactive rebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace `pick` by `reword` or (`r` for short). After you save and exit, you'll get another editor for each commit that you marked for rewording. The one-line commit message you see in the initial editor is for reference only; any changes to it seem to be ignored.